# Protecting Single Resource with HTTP/REST

Tags: spring, rest, http

There is a scenario in which a single piece of hardware is connected to a computer within a facility. This hardware needs to be accessed on premise by another computer on the network. A REST API can be used to communicate to the computer that has this hardware via the internal network.

The issue is that this hardware can only be used by a single user at a time, and on top of that, it takes time to process information. What is a good solution to implement such limits so that multiple people aren't trying to make HTTP requests at the same time?

One possible solution is to limit the endpoint with a username/password, but I am wondering what other elegant solutions exist. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that your are trying to solve a multithreading concurrent access problem. A solution could be to use `synchronized` to lock the code block that need to be access by a single user at a time